# Is separating django frontend and backend with API viable?

Tags: django, api

I'm used to Django and already developed website with a whole Django or with Django API + React.

For a side project, I'm thinking about creating a Django project with 2 apps:

1. Django API  2) Django Front.

I absolutely want to decouple front/back to be able to reuse the API in the future, and I like the view system from Django.

Is my idea making sense?

**Edit 1:**

To clarify.
App 1: Django API serving JSON.
App 2: Django App using API calls in the controllers to generate the views.

**Edit 2:**

I did a proof of concept and it works like a charm.
The only drawback is that I have to use Cookies to store the JWT token and maintain the session state, which is not convenient

Comment: not totally clear what you're asking. are you trying to ask if you can maintain both a REST API with JSON type responses and a traditional site with HTML page responses?

Comment: Yes, i the same Django Project

Comment: No matter where you put your front-end files, both are served from different servers. so you need to use [this](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers)  in your back end.

Comment: @Ameya This doesn't make sense if I'm inside the same Django project, on the same server.

Comment: @PierreAnken right this doesn't make sense how dumb I am! sorry 

Comment: you're thinking about the app separation wrong. the REST API is itself a view of your models and services. the traditional web interface is another view of those same models and services. seems like you're asking if you can have one set of views that consumes another set of views. when really both views should be consuming the same model and service layers... if you'd like a "view" that consumes your rest API views, but still functions like traditional web, you're substantially better off using some kind of SPA framework and SSR

Comment: This is sounds really interesting, if I may..
What is it that you trying to achieve by having a python(Django) front-end?

Comment: @theseeker avoid react I'm not good at :-P

Comment: @PierreAnken I figured….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible, but completely wrong with idea.

1. How it possible. Wrong version:
   Try to remember, how we can create integrate test for our view. We Should create client and send request to Django to your view-url with args kwargs querystring e.t.c.
   In response you have already answer. Try to imagine: part with client - is your Django front, requested part - your backend.

The same works not only in test, you can create request to ask something on the completely other server.

2. Redis/MemCashed e.t.c. (pattern sender/receiver) Wrong version:
   The Front Django speaks with Backend through Third part application. It can be faster.
3. "Pythonic" version. Right in your case:
   You can create Backend Django part like a library with views as interfaces.
   Frontend Django part is completely standalone, it import an use interfaces from library, which is your "BackEnd Module".

If you want - you can use "BackEnd Module" everywhere as import,  or you can start it as server and ask info per requests.

Completely independent in this case means, you can install "BackEnd Module" without "FrontEnd Module". "FrontEnd Module" can be installed standalone too and it should take from settings, which interfaces should be used as data-source.

I hope, i am right understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely separate front and back, remember, django just creates endpoints and consumes them with its own views, you can even use both.

Here is the documentation for django views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/#the-view-layer

You can use a librarie like React as frontend and connect to your api(django app) and use both.

Comment: My question is more about having one Django project, with 2 apps. One app being the API and the second one the "normal" website consuming it.

Comment: define normal, please

Comment: My wording was bad. I edited the question

Comment: Yeah, i think it does not make sense, if you want to keep using django views system just use it inside your first app. 
If you want to decouple them you should use of React or some other library for your frontend.